# AsyncDisplayKit - ASButton Size

Tags: swift, asyncdisplaykit

[Table Cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykVoS.png)

[image]
I'm learning to use Asyncdisplaykit. My result is in picture below.
But I don't know how to constraint button equal Screen.width/3, Its auto constraints equal image width. 
This is my code

```
    let controlStack = ASStackLayoutSpec(direction: ASStackLayoutDirection.Horizontal, spacing: 3.0, justifyContent: ASStackLayoutJustifyContent.Center, alignItems: ASStackLayoutAlignItems.Center, children: [self.mFavoriteButton, self.mCommentButton, self.mShareButton])
    controlStack.spacingAfter = 3.0
    controlStack.spacingBefore = 3.0

    let insetDateLayout = ASInsetLayoutSpec(insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: self.frame.size.width - 100, bottom: 0, right: 0), child: self.mDateTimeNode)
    let imageLayout = ASStaticLayoutSpec(children: [imagePlace, insetDateLayout])


    return ASStackLayoutSpec(direction: .Vertical, spacing: 3.0, justifyContent: ASStackLayoutJustifyContent.Start, alignItems: ASStackLayoutAlignItems.Center, children:[imageLayout, self.mMessageNode, controlStack])
```

Answer (score 2):

try change `ASStackLayoutAlignItems.Center` to `ASStackLayoutAlignItems.Stretch`. And try enable Grow Constraints for buttons (need to test it):

```
self.mFavoriteButton.flexGrow = true;
self.mCommentButton.flexGrow = true;
self.mShareButton.flexGrow = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Reply if you were able to address the problem!

Typically you want to use flexBasis with a relative size of 0.33 to do 1/3rd.  Check out documentation on Web / CSS flexbox for examples of flexbasis.